Gates belt drive front sprocket slowly being eaten
The front sprocket of my Gates belt drive bike is being slowly being eaten away by the belt. This leaves a layer of grey gunk all over the back half of the bike and the belt. I've checked the tension of the belt and it was too low, but now it's OK and the wear still seems to happen (see between the teeth in the pic, this is taken after a full-on brake-cleaner clean followed by a 7km ride). You can also see that there is not much left of the teeth.

The bike has been ridden for around 9000 km (5500 miles). Is this kind of wear normal or to be expected?
I've looked around at other pictures on this SE and the front sprocket on them seems to have no wear at all after for example 3000km.
Bike is an e-bike with Shimano E6100 motor and (afair) Nexus I5E 5-speed hub.

Related answer to another question. After 10k miles, answerer said the front sprocket "shows considerable wear."

This is my example, 3000 miles  (I think?) and a pretty OK front sprocket, no where as worn as mine. Hence the question.

This is an ebike - is it a mid drive or a hub motor?  I'm asking, does the motor power a wheel directly or via the belt ?

What cadence are you riding at? I can see potential for low RPM/High torque with lots of electric assist to induce this kind of a lot sooner than a human powered bike could possibly achieve.  (Presuming Mid drive motor)

Aluminium or stainless? They look aluminium. IMO If you have 9000km on the set that amount of wear is not super surprising. Not good either, maybe your tension isn’t in range?

My cadence is 60-80, the motor is mid-drive. I usually bike at the speed that the motor cuts out so that might be a factor as well. The sprocket is made of aluminium, the rear sprocket is steel and has no wear at all.

Getting 9000km from an e-bike drive train is exceptional! Now you need new cog, chainri... I mean a beltring and a belt. Pay closer attention to the belt tension with the new drive train and hopefully it will not get this bad. E-bike drive trains require a lot more maintenance due to the constant high torque.

Do pay for the stainless cog when you change out if you can. My CDX drivetrain with SS cogs still looks practically shop new after 12 months Including winter riding (acoustic bike)
